# Full computer name not displaying DNS Suffix

Tags: windows

I have a PC joined to Active Directory.

Under `System Properties > Computer Name` I noticed that “Full computer name:” is not displaying properly

PC is currently showing

```
Full computer name: COMPUTERNAME
```

Verus this:

```
Full computer name: COMPUTERNAME.domain.com
```

I have done some reading and found that the registry keys “Domain” and “NV Domain” under `HKLM\System\services\Tcpip\Parameters` are used in conjunction with the computer name to generate the “Full computer name:”

All the keys appear to be populated properly but I am still getting the name not displaying properly.

I have tried disjoining and rejoining the PC, and blanking the registry keys, rebooting, and repopulating the keys. Still no luck.

One thing that I have noticed about this client is that under the key `HKLM\System\services\Tcpip\Parameters\DNSRegisteredAdapaters` there are no entries.

I have compared to this computers that are showing the “Full computer name” properly and these computers have entries under this key. I am wondering if this has something to do with it. I can’t seem to get this key to generate.

Comment: what's in `%userdomain%`?

Comment: %userdomain% is populated with our pre-Windows 2000 domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out where the problem was.
I found this [post](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/20590-unable-join-domain-6.html) which referenced the following key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\System\DNSClient]
```

I went and checked for this key on the offending clients. Under DNSClient there were two additional keys

```
NV PrimaryDnsSuffix
PrimaryDnsSuffic
```

Each of these keys were blank

I then went on the computers there were working, and none of them had the DNSClient key.

So I went ahead and deleted the DNSClient key, rebooted, and now everything is showing as it should.

Hopefully this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be some issue in DHCP leases, which may have expired for your computer, where the hostname have not changed to FQDN.

Try to register the DNS using the command:

```
ipconfig /registerdns
```

Now clear the DNS cache on the machine. Check your DNS server for any 'A' record of the old name and remove them once the new A record appears.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did as you suggested. Unfortunately though it did not solve my issue. However, it did lead me to another issue I found during the creation of computer accounts when they are joined to the AD. Still trying to hunt down the FQDN issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I have about 100 workstations under AD with Dynamic DNS and Dynamic DHCP.  Some of the stations appear with FQDN (fully qualified domain names) and some appear with just the hostname.  I have yet to figure out a pattern why.

I believe that DDHCP gives the workstation the hostname and the workstation tells DDNS, but DDNS will only take it from the workstation if the ownership of the prior DNS record belongs to the workstation.

My solution is currently in development.  I have accumulated a sql table of MAC's and IP's and hostnames for all of my workstations and I am writing scripts to create DHCP reservations for all of the stations.  Then, with the stations locked to an IP, I can generate the zone files for the DNS server and take the arbitrary name assignments out of the hands of AD.

Also, BTW, I have boolean values in the workstation table that allows me to set whether a workstation needs a proxy or gets a crippled control panel and my GPO scripts read the table and sets up the workstation with every boot.  Stuff I cannot do with any degree of detail using Groups within AD.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Has your solution resolved the issue of the FQDN not showing in full? The ownership of the DNS record is an interesting thought. I can maybe try disjoining the machine and completely deleting all reference to it. Then reintroduce it to the network and AD and see what happens. I had noticed that when I added the machine to AD, the dnshostname and SPN attributes were empty. Not sure why, but I suspect this has something to do with why the FQDN is not showing properly.

Comment: My solution is not a short term project... I hope to use the end of year shutdown to make sweeping changes to the infrastructure, perhaps recreate the domain.  What the prior admin left me with is not optimal.  IMHO, MAC/IP/Name maintenance is a very small maintenance task in exchange for a huge degree of stability.  I am not a proponent of Dynamic DNS or DHCP.  IMHO they are for very lazy people.  I have only a few weeks left of this pandemonium, then I will a have rock solid foundation on which to run.

Comment: Also, I might add, I am having a devil of a time with IPV6.  Most of my workstations are XP or embedded and not very IPV6 friendly.  AD just loves to delete IPV4 addresses when the PDC and station both speak IPV6.  I have too many stations with an unpublished IPV4 address.  A hard coded zone table should fix that as well as reverse  DNS which likewise is a crap shoot.

Comment: I think that if you set it up and maintain it then it is best. I think where problems tend to sneak in is when you have "many hands in the pot". Getting everyone to follow procedure can be difficult. Not impossible though. At any rate, I still have yet to find a solution to this issue. I still can't nail down where the issue is though.